# MySQL; Get information from 3 table same time

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

People

here is my little problem.
I have three table:
a_names_1
b_names_2
c_names_3 
they are same by structure. all of them has two item: name and used

Is there any QUERY to run to get and count all the 'name' that has 'used'=1 from all those three tables together.

I've tried this one, but didn't work:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) 'name' from a_names_1) UNION 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 'name' from a_names_2) UNION 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 'name' from a_names_3) WHERE `used`=1
```

I'm using PHPMyAdmin for MySQL.

Any Help would be appreciated.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query outputs count of distinct `names` from all tables with `used=1`

```
select count(distinct name)
from
(
select name,used from a_names_1 where used=1
union all
select name,used from a_names_2 where used=1
union all
select name,used from a_names_3 where used=1
)  t
```

If you need to SUM all USED for each NAME from all tables and output only with SUM of used=1 then:

```
select count(*) from
(
select name, SUM(used)
from
(
select name,used from a_names_1
union all
select name,used from a_names_2
union all
select name,used from a_names_3
)  t
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(used)=1
) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as name 
from 
(
select name, used from a_names_1
union 
select name, used from a_names_2
union
select name, used from a_names_3) t
where t.used = 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't the WHERE want to be inside the subquery, otherwise there's no `used` column available to check?

Comment: well, there in three tables are over 1,8 million entry and it lags the server. when the query withmon table only takes 0.004 seconds to give a result.
is it okay to take that much time?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is slow, because you lose the index optimizations. What I would do is do the three queries, something like

```
SELECT SUM('name') AS name_sum
FROM ((SELECT COUNT(*) 'name' from a_names_1 WHERE `used`=1) 
     UNION (SELECT COUNT(*) 'name' from a_names_2 WHERE `used`=1));
```

If this doesn't work, it is probably a problem with the usage of name

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

it gives me this error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted this way:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from 
(
    select name from a_names_1 t1 where t1.used = 1
    union 
    select name from a_names_2 t2 where t2.used = 1
    union
    select name from a_names_3 t3 where t3.used = 1
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward solution;

```
SELECT SUM(used) FROM (
  SELECT used FROM a_names_1 WHERE used=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT used FROM a_names_2 WHERE used=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT used FROM a_names_3 WHERE used=1
) a
```

[SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/099be/8)

An alternative if you have an index on `used` (and the only values of used are 0 or 1) is to just do the counting using the index;

```
SELECT SUM(used) total FROM (
  SELECT SUM(used) used FROM a_names_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(used) FROM a_names_2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUM(used) FROM a_names_3
) a
```

[SQLfiddle for this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/736449/1).

If you look at the query plan of the latter query, you can see it uses the indexes effectively.